# Should a user profile be generated prior to use it as IIS Application Pool identity?

Tags: iis-7.5, iis-8, user-profile, application-pools

When using a custom profile as identity for an IIS (7.5, 8.0) Application Pool - is one supposed to login with this account on the related server in order to create a user profile beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

No, no need, the profile will be created automatically the first time the Application Pool is used.

If you need specific things in the profile you can/should create it first.

Comment: Thanks so far. One last question: What do you man by "Application Pool is used"? In detail I am asking about the term "used". Does "used" mean: Started AppPool with this user? Or: Having had the AppPool served the first request?

Comment: That depends, usually the profile is created when the first request is served, but if you set the property `Start Mode = AlwaysRunning`, then the profile is created as soon as you assign a web site to the AppPool.